# Searching locations in Solr

Tags: search, solr, street-address

I have four pieces of data that I want to make searchable.

**Town, City, Postcode, Country**

What is the best way that I can make these results searchable by any of the following ways:

- London, England
- Swindon, Wiltshire, England
- Wiltshire, England
- England
- Wiltshire
- Swindon

I could normalise the data, but then I would get duplicate results if someone searched for simply "London".

If I had only "London, England" stored, but not just "London", then if someone searched for "London" it wouldnt find any results.

Its a catch22. How should one store addresses to allow flexibility when the user is searching?

Comment: If you have "London, England" indexed, searches for "London" would match that. Could you add some samples of data you have, not just queries?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to use solr spatial search features http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch/ but that would require access to a mapping data service which could return the latitude / longitude of the location and store that with the solr record. Then do the same lookup on searching to get the latitude / longitude and you will be able to do radius searches and get much more accurate results compared to text searching on locations.

Answer (score 0):

is best to follow the suggestion of the previous answer. 
you should add a field location 
and configure schema.xml

added to the section  `<fieldType>`

```
 <fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>
```

added to the section `<field>`

```
<field name="location" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />

 <dynamicField name="*_coordinate"  type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="false"/>
```

Now update your index solr/dataimport?command=delta-import

can make your query  &q=*:*&fq={!geofilt pt=45.15,-93.85 sfield=store d=5}

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearchDev

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the geospatial data available you could give [Herarchical Faceting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HierarchicalFaceting) a try. It indexes the data in a specific manner, allowing queries within a hierarchy, e.g.:

```
Document: England > London > Chelsea

Index: 0/England, 1/England/London, 2 England/London/Chelsea

Query: facet.field = category, facet.prefix = 1/London, facet.mincount = 1
```

There is some redundancy in the index, but it should be negligable in most cases.